# Quotient Groups of $\mathbb{R}$ x $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: group-theory

Another Group Theory Homework Problem:

Let G be a group.
Let H be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ x $\mathbb{R}$ where $\mathbb{R}$ has operation addition and therefore a neutral element (0,0):

H = {(x,y): y = 2x}

(a) Prove that H is a normal subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ x $\mathbb{R}$.
(b) In geometrical terms, describe the elements of the quotient group G/H.
(c) In geometrical terms or otherwise, describe the operation of G/H.

What I know with part (a):
A normal subgroup is closed with respect to conjugates. --> for any a as an element of H and x as an element of G, xax^(-1) is an element of H.
In otherwords... a normal subgroup is any nonempty subset of G which is closed with respect to products, with respect to inverses, and with respect to conjugates.

My issue here is taking this definition and turning into a cartesian product. Do I take some n,m as elements of G and do something with (n,m)(2x,y)(n,m)^(-1)?

As for (b) and (c) I know that H is the set of all even numbers, by any x is multiplied by 2 with result y, which will be even.

Any tips/insight to clear my mind would be wonderful!

Comment: In your first paragraph, presumably $G$ is the specific group $\left(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}, (+)\times (+)\right)$ - that is, the structure $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, with component-wise addition as the group operation?  That's unclear from the question.

Comment: Yes! Sorry about that. $\mathbb{R}$ has addition as the group operation.

Comment: Normality is trivial since the groups in question are all Abelian, so any subgroup is normal. You can just focus on showing it's a subgroup. Edit: Also no sense in saying $y$ will be even since you are dealing with real numbers. $y$ can be any real number.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  All elements of $H$ are points on a line $l$ with equation $y=2x$. So, geomtrically, the cosets should correspond to parallel lines.  In each case, a displacement vector acts as a coset repesentative. Can you figure out from this how to describe the operation on the quotient group in geometric terms?